# count results from a case statement

Tags: count, case-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to count the number of occurrences based on a `case` statement:

```
select
case
when name.ssn > 0
 then 'YES'
when name.taxid > 0
 then 'NO'
else 'OTHER' end "Category",
name.created
from
name
where
name.id = 11111
```

I now want to return the count of `YES`s, `OTHER`s, and `NO`s in one column but can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to count the result over group by statement

```
select count(col),col from(   
select
case
when name.ssn > 0
 then 'YES'
when name.taxid > 0
 then 'NO'
else 'OTHER' end as col,
name.created
from
name
where
name.id = 11111
) group by col;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a subquery?